# Spark dataframe.map() processed each row more than once

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Running this code:

(1)

```
val resultDf = myDataFrame.map(row => { println(s"$row"); return row })
```

I can see exactly one print out (use "yarn logs -applicationId xxxx" to get the log) for each row. However when the processing code is more complex:

(2)

```
val resultDf = myDataFrame.map(row => { println(s"$row"); /* complex processing code */})
```

I find about 2 or 3 times more print out than the actual row count. But in both cases `myDataFrame.count == resultDf.count`

**Question:** in case (2) I see more print out, is that because Spark runs dataFrame.map() in more containers for redundancy, and throws away extra results when redundant executions all return successfully? Thanks.

BTW I run spark jobs on aws emr, spark 3.1.2

Comment: BTW has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Every row is processed exactly once using `map`. Could you share how you process rows in snippet (2)?

Answer (score 0):

The result dataframe passed on downstream, at one point it's not cached but referenced 3 times, resulting in multiple executions of myDataFrame.map().